# Android connect to Azure SQL Database and select statement

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sql-server, azure

I am trying to connect an android mobile app to a database on Azure portal. I have my connection class below (obviously with the correct fields from Azure Connection)

```
public class ConnectionClass {

String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection CONN() {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    String ConnURL = null;
    try {

        Class.forName(classs);
        ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://name.database.windows.net:1433;database=name;user=un;password=xxx;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}
}
```

I am trying to read from a table on the database like below:

```
    public class FillList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String z = "";

    List<Map<String, String>> prolist  = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pbbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {

        pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(AddProducts.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String[] from = { "A", "B", "C" };
        int[] views = { R.id.lblproid, R.id.lblproname,R.id.lblprodesc };
        final SimpleAdapter ADA = new SimpleAdapter(AddProducts.this,
                prolist, R.layout.lsttemplate, from,
                views);
        lstpro.setAdapter(ADA);


        lstpro.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                HashMap<String, Object> obj = (HashMap<String, Object>) ADA
                        .getItem(arg2);
                proid = (String) obj.get("A");
                String proname = (String) obj.get("B");
                String prodesc = (String) obj.get("C");
                edtprodesc.setText(prodesc);
                edtproname.setText(proname);
           //     qty.setText(qtys);
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
            if (con == null) {
                z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
            } else {
                String query = "select * from Training";
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                ArrayList<String> data1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    datanum.put("A", rs.getString(1));
                    data1.add(rs.getString(1));
                    datanum.put("B", rs.getString(2));
                    data1.add(rs.getString(2));
                    datanum.put("C", rs.getString(3));
                    prolist.add(datanum);
                }


                z = "Success";
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            z = "Error retrieving data from table";

        }
        return z;
    }
}
```

However it just runs to the exception z:

> Error retrieving data from table

Can someone direct me to where I am going wrong? Is there an alternative way of retrieving this table data? The tables where build in Visual Studio and stored on Azure.

Comment: Difficult to say right now. Did you try to use proof of concept tutorial on connecting from Java to SQL Azure? Could you please try and see if that is working? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt720656.aspx Check if your IP is in the approved to access list in the SQL Azure firewall on the dashboard.

Comment: Can you code step it and see which line it fails on? What information does the Exception object ex give?

Comment: Hi @RichardCL, the Exception given is : java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name 'Training'. I am a complete novice in SQL can you help with this issue?

Comment: Ok, that's useful. (1) Can you code step and confirm which statement is throwing the exception. It's probably "ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
", but I'd like to be sure. (2) Are you connecting to the right database? (3) What schema does the Training table belong to? It's good practice to prefix object names with the schema, eg "dbo.Training". (4) Can you connect to the database in Azure using SSMS and execute this query successfully?

Comment: As a general point, in your system, you need to report or log the information in exceptions, otherwise it is very difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: @RichardCL thank you so much for your help. From stepping through the code I found an error in my connection string by changing it to databaseName="dbname", it connected correctly. Thank you so much